# MS Access 2016 File Browse Button Issues

Tags: vbscript, ms-access-2016

I am using the script listed below (I honestly stole this probably from this very site) for a browse button on a form. The task is simply to start up MS File Dialog box so that a file (in this case an image file) can be selected. Once you select the record and click ok it then pastes the file name and location into a field. 
Viewing the table the file name and location is pasted just as it should be. The problem comes in with a report I built. I have an image set to display with the control source linked back to that file address field. It will not display the image though.
However, if I manually type the same address character for character or even “copy”, delete, and then “paste” the same exact entry into the field the image then displays just fine on the report. 
I have checked to make sure there are no spaces or characters anywhere there shouldn’t be. I am at a loss here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and I will gladly give you my first born. Ok maybe not the first I like him but you can have the second one, she’s hell.

```
Private Sub Command67_Click()

 On Error GoTo SubError
    'Add "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library" in references
    Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3
'Dim FD As Office.FileDialog
Dim FDialog As Object
Dim varfile As Variant
Set FDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

EmployeePicture = ""

' Set up the File Dialog
Set FDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FDialog
    .Title = "Choose the spreadsheet you would like to import"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"  'Folder picker needs trailing slash

    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All", "*.*"

    If .Show = True Then
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            'User clicked open but didn't select a file
            GoTo SubExit
        End If

        'An option for MultiSelect = False
        'varFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        'EmployeePicture = varFile

        'Needed when MultiSelect = True
        For Each varfile In .SelectedItems
            EmployeePicture = EmployeePicture & varfile & vbCrLf
        Next
    Else
        'user cancelled dialog without choosing!
        'Do you need to react?
    End If

End With


SubExit:
On Error Resume Next
    Set FDialog = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SubError:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
        "An error occurred"
    GoTo SubExit

End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing the `vbCrLf` in `EmployeePicture = EmployeePicture & varfile & vbCrLf` . Or, `EmployeePicture = varfile`

Comment: I am not sure how or why but IT WORKED!!! You are an absolute genius! I honestly can't thank you enough.

Comment: No worries.. It must have been the [vbCrLf ( vb Carriage Return Line Feed)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh277t8e.aspx) at the end which caused the error in your report.